# Azure Vmss Vm uptime

Tags: azure, powershell

Is there a way to find Vm uptime? I need to find the VM's which are running more than 6 hours in Vmss using powershell. I am able to get Virtual machines in Vmss and its status(running/deallocated).I tried to run

```
Get-azurermlog
```

command to get the event log of vm start time but couldn't find the result.
Vm os-linux,windows.
Can you please guide me to create a powershell script which display vm uptime. Thanks for the help in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally! I was able to get the VM uptime from

```
(Get-AzureRmVmssVM -ResourceGroupName $vmssRg -VMScaleSetName $vmssName -InstanceView -InstanceId $instanceId).Statuses.Time.Date
```